# R Shiny dashboard tabName not working with menuItem and nested input

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

tabName not picked up in menuItem for shinydashboard when a nested input is included. Any ideas on a workaround ?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sbm",
                menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard"),
                menuItem("Select Something", tabName = "select_smt",
                  selectInput("inputTest", "Input Test",choices = c("a", "b"))
                  ),
                menuItem("No Select", tabName = "no_select")
                )
    ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",h2("Dashboard with no nest input")),
      tabItem(tabName = "select_smt",h2("Content with nested input")),
      tabItem(tabName = "no_select", h2("No nested input"))
    ) #
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/28#issuecomment-108616851) is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @SBista thanks that worked for what I wanted.